# box-shadow is not a gradient, how can I get a gradient shadow on my button?

Tags: html, gradient, css

I have just discovered that CSS `box-shadow` is not a gradient.

I want to have under my link element, which is shown as a button, is a gradient which goes from one RGB color to another RGB color, and this looks like a drop shadow. The top RGB color is `#333` and the button RGB color to be `#fff` and it should have a height of 4 pixels. (just for example, I have not measured this from the button image).

So I have a

```
<a href="#" class="mybutton">Button</a>.
```

I want the shadow directly under it.

The button with a gradient shadow under it I am trying to reproduce is this one:

[image]

Is there any equivalent way to do this with box-shadow or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: What CSS have you tried, and what do your results look like? The image of the button you posted looks doable with `box-shadow`.

Comment: The problem is, I have many gradients in a database I need to show as box-shadows. So although this instance could be approximated by trial and error box-shadow, I need a more reliable way to do it.

Comment: This is done with multiple `text-shadow`s, but the same technique could be applied to `box-shadow`: http://jaredhardy.com/omg-text/

Comment: @cimmanon I could generate this type of thing from code, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like the following (although you're going to have to play a bit with the colours etc you prefer):

```
<a href="#" class="btn">Button</a>​​​​​​​​​​​

.btn {
    border: solid 1px rgb(139,137,125); 
    border-color: rgb(182,179,161) rgb(167,164,146) rgb(139,137,125) rgb(167,164,146); 
    background: #C9C6B4; /* old browsers */ 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #D8D5C1 3%, #C9C6B4 4%, #A7A492 100%); /* firefox */ 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(3%, #D8D5C1), color-stop(4%, #C9C6B4), color-stop(100%, #A7A492)); /* webkit */ /*    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#D8D5C1', endColorstr='#A7A492',GradientType=0 );*/ 
    -moz-text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px -1px 0px; 
    -webkit-text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px -1px 0px; 
    text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px -1px 0px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 0px 2px 3px; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 0px 2px 3px; 
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 0px 2px 3px;
    cursor: pointer; 
    font: bold 12px/1em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    color: rgb(255,255,255)!important; 
    text-align: center; 
    white-space: nowrap; 
    float: right; 
    margin: 0 0 8px 5px; 
    padding: 0.5em 1em; 
}

.btn:hover {
    border-color: rgb(211,106,13) rgb(185,72,0) rgb(166,53,0) rgb(185,72,0); 
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0px 1px 2px; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0px 1px 2px; 
    -moz-text-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 0px 0px 10px; 
    -webkit-text-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 0px 0px 10px; 
    text-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 0px 0px 10px; 
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0px 1px 2px; 
    background: #DD6C00; /* old browsers */ 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F69C11 3%, #DD6C00 4%, #BB4A00 100%);  /* firefox */ 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(3%, #F69C11), color-stop(4%, #DD6C00), color-stop(100%, #BB4A00));
}
```

Nick

Comment: Hi Nick, how do you get that? by trial and error ? do you guess the values then compare it with the image? or do you have another method?

Comment: Hey Phil, if you're referring to the gradient colours, I use this website http://gradients.glrzad.com/
You choose the colours that you like, preview them in a sample and the CSS gets automatically created for you.